# itfoxtec-identity-saml2 SAML Request Destination Port being stripped out

Tags: port, uri, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

On making a SAML request the port number (443) is being stripped out of the Destination. I understand this is default behaviour of the URI object. However the SAML identity provider requires the destination includes the port number for validation.

How can I get the SAML builder to include the port? 443 is being stripped from https://sit-api.eat.xxxxxx.xxxx.xx:443/samlsso (see below)

```
            Saml2Configuration samlconfig = GetSAMLConfig();

            var samlRequest = new Saml2AuthnRequest(samlconfig);
            samlRequest.AssertionConsumerServiceUrl = new Uri(_appConfiguration["Saml2:AssertionConsumerServiceUrl"]); 

            samlRequest.Destination = new Uri(_appConfiguration["Saml2:SingleSignOnDestination"]); // https://sit-api.eat.xxxxxx.xxxx.xx:443/samlsso

            samlRequest.NameIdPolicy = new NameIdPolicy()
            {
                AllowCreate = false,
                Format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent",
                SPNameQualifier = _appConfiguration["Saml2:SPNameQualifier"]
            };

            samlRequest.Conditions = new Condition();
            samlRequest.Conditions.Items = new List<ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Schemas.Conditions.ICondition>();
            samlRequest.Conditions.Items.Add(new ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Schemas.Conditions.AudienceRestriction() { Audiences = new List<Audience>() { new Audience() { Uri = _appConfiguration["Saml2:AllowedAudienceUris"] } } });

            var bnd = binding.Bind(samlRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the destination URL after the `ToActionResult` method has been called if you are using a `Saml2RedirectBinding`. And thereby overriding the default behavior.

Like this:

```
var action = binding.ToActionResult() as RedirectResult;
action.Url = action.Url.Replace("https://sit-api.eat.xxxxxx.xxxx.xx/samlsso", "https://sit-api.eat.xxxxxx.xxxx.xx:443/samlsso");
return action;
```